# How to implement a stopwatch countdown using Ember.run.later

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ember.js

The solution boils down to "How to clear interval of `Ember.run.later`"

```
  class CountdownTimer {

  constructor() {
    this.counterContinue = false;
  }

  start() {
    this.counterContinue = true;
    this.decreaseCounterLoop();
  }

  stop() {
    this.counterContinue = false;
  }

  decreaseCounterLoop() {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      //do work

      if (this.counterContinue) {
        this.decreaseCounterLoop();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

I tried to implement a countdown timer where I can start and stop at will. But currently this has a bug.

I call `stop()`, and call `start()` again quick enough so the `decreaseCounterLoop` starts looping **twice** a second.

Comment: I don't actually use `setTimeout` so don't post a solution specific to `setTimeout`

Comment: So what are you using then ?

Comment: I use `Ember.run.later` from emberjs.com

Comment: Then figure out how you'd do the same as `clearTimeout` in Ember

Comment: If you don't want a solution with setTimeout, I might respectfully suggest an alteration to your post title that says "How to implement....using setTimeout"

Comment: I wanted a `setTimeout` solution without using `clearTimeout` post it if possible @DavidW

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm thinking, somewhere, your 'this' references are getting crossed up and causing something to be called in a manner you're not expecting. I'd suggest declaring a local variable to hold a reference to 'this' in the class, then access your instance methods internally across that variable (think closures).

Comment: @DavidW ok, I found the equivalent and posted as answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to approach this, but the issue in the code you posted is that the timeout isn't cleared when stop is called - which means, as you noticed, that you can end up with two loops running.

```
class CountdownTimer {

    constructor() {
      this.timeout = null;
    }

    start() {
      this.decreaseCounterLoop();
    }

    stop() {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }

  decreaseCounterLoop() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this, function() {
      //do work
      this.decreaseCounterLoop();
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

I haven't used Ember but the same logic should work using [Ember.run.cancel](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_cancel).

Answer (score 0):

This is the Ember equivalent of `clearTimeout`:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_cancel